# A quiz which requires a user to register and sign in

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to allow a user to first register and then sign in to take a quiz. I’m finding it difficult as the users details such as name, age and year group as well as username and password need to be saved to a text file. I have some of the code for registration already completed but I'm still confused.

```
            #quiz which tests a students knowledge
            print "Welcome to my quiz!"

            start = raw_input("Do you need to register or sign in?") #initial start up question
            if start == "register": #registration
                name = raw_input("What is your name?")
                age = raw_input("What age are you?")
                yearGroup = raw_input("What year of school are you in?")
                username = (name[:3]+age)
                print "You username is", username
                password = raw_input("Please input a password which you will remember.")
                text_file = open("user_info.txt", "w")
                array = [name, age, yearGroup, username, password]
                text_file.write(array)
                text_file.close()
            elif start == "sign in": #signing in
                userEntry = raw_input("Please enter your username")
```

Comment: Firstly, don't bother learning Python 2, use Python 3. Now, concerning your problem, there are two good ways to make up your mind how the program should behave: One option is to write in plain English what you expect the program to do. Keep this text as comments in your program when writing the actual code. The other option is to draw a flowchart, which also translates to code easily. As it stands, you haven't described what you want (I guess you yourself don't know yet) and thus there is not even a real problem to solve yet.

Comment: It had to be done on python 2 as this is the platform that is available in my school. I have drawn out a flowchart but I am unsure how to save the users details to a text file. I think that it has to be done using an array. Also when the user takes a quiz their score has to be saved next to their details but I do not know how to save it to this specific user.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that you are writing the user data to the text file in the form of a list. when you try to read it from the file you will get a string that looks like `"[name, age, yearGroup, username, password]"`. instead of turning it into a list, format it into a string with something like `name+" "+str(age)+" "`etc. then write it to the file. when you read the file you will get another string. Each user will be on a different line because you wrote them in sepperately so you can use `.split("\n")`. this will create an array where each element is a line in the file. Then you have to iterate through that and do `.split()` with no parameters (it automatically splits by any/all white space). If you apply all of this to get a list `content` where each element is the user data in the format `[name, age, yearGroup, username, password]` you will have:

```
f = open("user_info.txt", "r")

content = f.read()

content = content.split("\n")

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].split()

f.close()
```

if you want to turn the integer elements back to integers, then modify the for loop to do so:

```
for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].split()
    for j in range(len(content[i])):
        try:
            content[i][j] = int(content[i][j])
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I understand it now but I am unsure how to save the users scores beside their data so they can look back on their previous grades. @hexidian

Comment: another solution would be to create a new text file for each user (i.e `username+".txt"` and then you could have the first line be basic info gotten at the beginning, with each line after that being a score.

Comment: oh yes I could do that! The only thing that would restrict me is that at the end of each quiz the user gets to see their score and also the highest score and the details of the user with the highest score. And so if everyone’s score is in a different text file wouldn’t it be difficult to find the highest score?

Comment: I'm confused on what this part of the code does:                                                       f = open("user_info.txt", "r")

content = f.read()

content = content.split("\n")

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].split()

f.close()

Comment: the `f = open("user_info.txt","r")` makes `f` the file you are opening and the designation with the string `"r"` means you are going to read from the file. `f.read()` will return a string which is the contents of the file. `content.split("\n")` will return a list, which will be the contents of the file cut at the end of each line. then the code iterates through this new list and splits each element at every space, so if you had one element as `"hello thing 12"` you would get `["hello","thing","12"]` the `f.close` at the end is just good practice. If you don't close the file you can get errors.